# Does it consider bad practice to return the remaining of a collection after DELETE

Tags: rest, http

Assuming we have a rest api, and a collection (with maximum 15 items).
The client is issuing a `DELETE` of one of the items in the collection.
Is it consider bad practice to return the remaining items in the collection? Should the `DELETE` return always empty body? If it is not a bad practice, what is the right status code?

My main question is, having a list of `items`, I `DELETE` one, is it ok to return a list of the `remaining items`?

Answer (score 2):

As defined in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5):

> If a DELETE method is successfully applied, the origin server
> SHOULD    send a 202 (Accepted) status code if the action will likely
> succeed    but has not yet been enacted, a 204 (No Content) status
> code if the    action has been enacted and no further information is
> to be supplied,    or a 200 (OK) status code if the action has been
> enacted and the    response message includes a representation
> describing the status.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) has an example for it:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT

<html>
  <body>
    <h1>File deleted.</h1> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, if your collection is a resource in and of itself, then a DELETE should delete the entirety of the collection (not a part of it) in which case I'd return 200 OK upon successful deletion.

If you want to DELETE one specific resource (not a collection), then delete that at its own URI and return 200 OK as well.

Just don't usurp the DELETE to essentially update a collection.

So no. Don't return the remainder of the collection. Return a status code.